# How do I identify similar dynamic elements with same id uniquely with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

So I have these elements, generated by a PHP loop:

```
<input id="toggler" data-toggle="toggle" data-id="1" data-size="small" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input id="toggler" data-toggle="toggle" data-id="2" data-size="small" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input id="toggler" data-toggle="toggle" data-id="3" data-size="small" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

This uses JQuery UI's toggler.

Now what I want to do, is simply, when one of them is checked or unchecked by the user, send through an ajax call to unpublish them in the DB.

```
var base = "http://whatever.com/";
var id = $(this).data(id);
var formData = {id:id};

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base+'unpublish',
        data: formData,
        success: function(data) {
        // data is ur summary
                $('#result').html(data);
            }

        });
```

Question: How do I uniquely identify each element without having to name each specifically?

Thanks

Comment: Id have to be unique. And I am typing this comment for 3342th time. :)

Comment: your markup is invalid .. **id's must be unique**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to have an easy way to access multiple elements they should use a common **CLASS** not ID.  IDs must be unique within a HTML document so as others have mentioned your HTML is invalid.

You could do something like this:

```
<input class="toggler" id="1" data-toggle="toggle" data-id="1" data-size="small" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input class="toggler" id="2" data-toggle="toggle" data-id="2" data-size="small" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input class="toggler" id="3" data-toggle="toggle" data-id="3" data-size="small" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

You can find them all in jQuery by referencing the class:

```
$( ".toggler" )
```

Comment: This is an oversimplification of solution .... OP then needs access to data to send also. There isn't much more here than what is mentioned in comments already

Answer (score 2):

You know you must have **one** unique `id` in a single document--remove them from your loop.

```
var base = "http://whatever.com/";

$('*[data-toggle="toggle"]').on('click', function(){

  var target = $(this),
      action = (target.is(':checked') ? 'unpublish' : 'publish'), // get action type based on checkbox checked attribute.
      id     = target.attr('data-id');

  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: base+action,
      data: {id:id},
      success: function(data) {
          // data is ur summary
          $('#result').html(data);
          // update checked attribute.
          (target.is(':checked') ? target.prop('checked',false) : target.prop('checked',true));
      }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Question: How do I uniquely identify each element without having to
>   name each specifically?

As pointed out at comments and Answers, `id` of element should be unique. You can remove `id` from elements and identify each element by its `data-id` attribute, which are unique at `html` at Question.

```
<input data-toggle="toggle" data-id="1" data-size="small" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input data-toggle="toggle" data-id="2" data-size="small" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input data-toggle="toggle" data-id="3" data-size="small" data-on="Yes" data-off="No" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

---

```
   $("input[data-id=1]") // first `input`
   $("input[data-id=2]") // second `input`
   $("input[data-id=3]") // third `input`
```